# How to change permalink for pages in WordPress?

Tags: permalinks

My permalink is set to custom structure:/%postname%.php in WordPress. It is fine for posts. But the permalink for pages does not end with .php. If I change the permalink when editing a page, i.e., change "my-page" to "my-page.php", after I click "ok", the link changes to "my-page-php" rather than "my-page.php". How to add a suffix to the permalink of pages?

Answer (score 0):

Your words say, you need to customize your web url. But the way (.something) is domain name or default web pages name. That's why you need to use other character except (.)